# SQL convert function gives unreadable results

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL code:

```
select SUBSTRING(PRJC.NAME,1,35), CONVERT(varchar,CCCBUDGETDATE,101) as Date, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),SUM(INBUDGETAMT)) +' --- '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),SUM(OUTBUGDETAMT)) AS INOUT
from PRJC, CCCPRJCBUDGET 
where PRJC.PRJC=CCCPRJCBUDGET.PRJC and FISCPRD=:X.SYS.FISCPRD and PERIOD=:X.SYS.PERIOD group by PRJC.NAME, CCCBUDGETDATE
```

The output is strange numbers as following: 2.90005e+006 --- 1.17205e+006

Why is not a clear number my output and I got the strange characters 'e+006' ?

Comment: That is "Scientific Notation."

Comment: what's the type of the inbudgetamt/outbudgetamt? It's probably a float, so your'e getting exactly what you should be: Floats convertd to varchar

Comment: Yes it's a float. Does any way to get the number without the scientific notation at the end?

Comment: Yes, make it a smaller number.  The scientific notation is not the problem; you're almost certainly getting bad numbers from your query, unless you really think the numbers are supposed to be that large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove Scientific Notation, simply replace 
`CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),SUM(OUTBUGDETAMT))` 
with 
`SUM(OUTBUGDETAMT)`

Comment: I got the following error: Ole Error: 80040E07. Error converting data type varchar to float

Comment: So OUTBUGDETAMT is of data type varchar. Convert it to a float before you try to sum it. SQL Server would be `SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT,OUTBUGDETAMT))` but I don't think your platform is SQL Server! It may work nevertheless. Tell us which platform you are using.

Comment: And it's possible you have values which simply cannot be converted to a float. They may contain letters, for example...